# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'linenumber'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, routes

I have a controller and that uses View, but when I try to run this View as a way to check my form. It does not load only i get this error from the browser.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
> 'lineNumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
> 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in
> 'OrderApplicationXML.Controllers.OrderHeaderController'. An optional
> parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
> an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters.

The routing config is correct, I don't know what else could be main reason for this and stuck. Please assist me.

```cs
// Routing.config
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OrderLineEdit",
            url: "OrderLine/Edit/{lineNumber}",
            defaults: new { controller = "OrderHeader", action = "Edit" }
            );

// model
public class OrderLine
{    
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public decimal CostPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal SalesPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}
```

```
// view
@model OrderApplicationXML.Models.OrderLine

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "OrderHeader", new { lineNumber = Model.LineNumber }, FormMethod.Post))

{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCode)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductType)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductType, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CostPrice)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CostPrice, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesPrice)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SalesPrice, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
}
```

Controller:

```cs
// GET: OrderLine/Edit/{LineNumber}
public ActionResult Edit(int  lineNumber)
{

    OrderLine orderLine = GetOrderLineByLineNumber(lineNumber);

    if (orderLine == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(orderLine);
}

private OrderLine GetOrderLineByLineNumber(int lineNumber)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-C5QD55P\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SalesOrder;Integrated Security=True";

    OrderLine orderLine = null;
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM OrderLine WHERE LineNumber = @LineNumber";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LineNumber", lineNumber);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read())
        {
            orderLine = new OrderLine
            {
                LineNumber = (int)reader["LineNumber"],
                ProductCode = reader["ProductCode"].ToString(),
                ProductType = reader["ProductType"].ToString(),
                CostPrice = (decimal)reader["CostPrice"],
                SalesPrice = (decimal) reader["SalesPrice"],
                Quantity = (int) reader["Quantity"]
            };
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    return orderLine; // Return the retrieved order line or null if not found
}
```

```
// POST

// POST: OrderHeader/Edit
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Update the order line in the database
            UpdateOrderLine(orderLine);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(orderLine);
    }
```

// controller

```
     // GET: OrderLine/Edit/{LineNumber}
                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Edit(int lineNumber)
                {
        
           OrderLine orderLine = GetOrderLineByLineNumber(lineNumber);
if (orderLine == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
    
                return View(orderLine);
            }
    

@model OrderApplicationXML.Models.OrderLine

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "OrderHeader", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCode)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Check the generated action for your form in html.

Comment: @TanveerBadar can you perhaps tell me what is wrong with it? Maybe i can able to understand where the issue is